# Create new Java object every time or reuse one

Tags: java, object, memory

I am generating many ModelAndView objects in my controller (one per web page I send) but I don't know which strategy will save more memory and will be better in performance.

These are my two options:

1- Keep an attribute in my Controller and reuse it every time:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{
    private ModelAndView mav;

    public ModelAndView methodA() {
        mav = new ModelAndView(...);

        return mav;
    }

    public ModelAndView methodB() {
        mav = new ModelAndView(...);

        return mav;
    }

...
}
```

2- Create one object foreach method:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{

    public ModelAndView methodA() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(...);

        return mav;
    }

    public ModelAndView methodB() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(...);

        return mav;
    }

...

}
```

It is any important improvement in one of them?
Thank you

Comment: Neither one should be your concern.  Thread matching the model map to the appropriate request is the biggest issue.  Opt for #2, not #1.  The mutable shared state will only bring you grief.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is so hard to match the model to the request? In what sense?

Comment: No, it's not hard, especially when you create one for each request.  That's my point.

Comment: @duffymo Yes, I try to do like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely avoid #1 for concurrency reasons.  You could have thread A running method 1 and thread B running method 2, and one of the will change the mav object before the other one can use the one it constructed.

Comment: Do you suggest `@Controller`s as Singleton?

Comment: A Spring MVC controller is a bean, so you could make it Prototype rather than Singleton.  It's singleton by default.  If you specify prototype scope, example 1 would be threadsafe since the front controller would create a new instance for each request.  Personally, singleton feels more comfortable to me, probably because java servlets (also controllers) are instantiated only once per jvm.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is not supposed to change state, meaning that you wish to maintain it then you can use a singleton and stop creating new instances each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that singleton pattern is what you are looking for :-)

good explanation with example here : http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html